# Problem when starting a nix-shell in the plututs repo

Tags: plutus, ubuntu, nixos, nix

I was doing the plutus pioneer program and ran into an error when starting a `nix-shell` at the top-level directory of the plutus-repository.

I ran into the same error on `Ubuntu  20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64)`  and `NixOS (20.09.4029.4a154d47623 (Nightingale) on VirtualBox)`.

I also did set up the IOHK binary caches on both systems.

I got the following error when running `nix-shell`:

```
error: build of '/nix/store/z6w41a6dv151g2q95v91yywid7s8mkn5-Agda-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

The `nix-shell --show-trace` command shows the following error:

```
error: while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'ghc-shell-for-packages' at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/builder/shell-for.nix:115:5:
while evaluating 'chooseDevOutputs' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/attrsets.nix:475:22, called from undefined position:
while evaluating 'mergeInputs' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix:14:17, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix:32:23:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/builder/shell-for.nix:57:20, called from undefined position:
while evaluating the attribute 'name' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:7:7:
while evaluating 'sanitizeDerivationName' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/strings.nix:746:28, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:7:14:
while evaluating 'pipe' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:61:15, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/strings.nix:746:36:
while evaluating 'reverseApply' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:62:27, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:63:8:
while evaluating the attribute 'version' at /home/demo/plutus/nix/pkgs/default.nix:68:15:
while evaluating the attribute 'extraPackages.Agda' at /home/demo/plutus/nix/pkgs/haskell/extra.nix:98:31:
while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs' at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:546:15:
while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs' at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:526:43:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/lib/import-and-filter-project.nix:5:1, called from /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:504:27:
build of '/nix/store/z6w41a6dv151g2q95v91yywid7s8mkn5-Agda-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I couldn't find anything online or in the cardano forum.

EDIT: running `nix-shell --show-trace` I have the additional error:

```
error: while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'ghc-shell-for-packages' at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/builder/shell-for.nix:117:5:
while evaluating 'chooseDevOutputs' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/attrsets.nix:475:22, called from undefined position:
while evaluating 'mergeInputs' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix:14:17, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix:31:17:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/builder/shell-for.nix:61:20, called from undefined position:
while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'plutus-metatheory-lib-plutus-metatheory-0.1.0.0' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:192:11:
while evaluating the derivation attribute 'name' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:7:7:
while evaluating 'sanitizeDerivationName' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/strings.nix:746:28, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:7:14:
while evaluating 'pipe' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:61:15, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/strings.nix:746:36:
while evaluating 'reverseApply' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:62:27, called from /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/trivial.nix:63:8:
while evaluating the attribute 'version' at /cloud/cloud-lite/training/plutus-pioneer-program/plutus-other-repo/plutus/nix/pkgs/default.nix:67:15:
while evaluating the attribute 'extraPackages.Agda' at /cloud/cloud-lite/training/plutus-pioneer-program/plutus-other-repo/plutus/nix/pkgs/haskell/extra.nix:18:3:
while evaluating 'hackage-package' at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:456:11, called from /cloud/cloud-lite/training/plutus-pioneer-program/plutus-other-repo/plutus/nix/pkgs/haskell/extra.nix:18:10:
while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs.Agda' at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:536:15:
while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs' at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:516:43:
while evaluating 'mkCabalProjectPkgSet' at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:152:13, called from /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:501:30:
while evaluating the attribute 'buildPackages.haskell-nix.compiler."${(((plan-pkgs).pkgs  hackage)).compiler.nix-name}".version' at /nix/store/qrbp0y6mfscqhfhzivnhc91hvby45nv7-nixpkgs-src/lib/attrsets.nix:344:7:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/lib/import-and-filter-project.nix:5:1, called from /nix/store/cf4ksa58yibwkmx2z83y7qd9zwpyjwmy-haskell.nix-src/overlays/haskell.nix:503:31:
build of '/nix/store/42ml953fywhg2i2fi4mqkq64v4fy512d-Agda-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed
```

Comment: On what revision of the plutus repository were you seeing this error?

Comment: Latest release, i just cloned it yesterday.

Comment: Yes it looks like it's the same error,I'm still trying to fix it with no success so far. 
Which discord community are you referring to ?

Comment: Dunno if the link will work for you, for me it's a IOHK discord channel: https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/826822689427554365 moreover I have opened a github issue for Haskell.Nix in case they can help find the problem which seems to occur in the nix derivation of this library: https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/issues/1109

Comment: I have suggested this question as a dupplicate, because if you look at the entire log it contains the same error warning: `hash mismatch in fixed-output derivation '/nix/store/7y3jr1jvzkj2146h7sivw0sfr2bhap3j-ghc-8.4.4-x86_64-deb8-linux.tar.xz`  like in the question Hash MisMatch Error on Plutus and Nix https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/367/hash-mismatch-error-on-plutus-and-nix . It is much more focussed on the real issue according to me. I gave the same answer: setting up the IOHK binary cache for nix

Answer (score 0):

This question is indeed a dupplicate of [Hash MisMatch Error on Plutus and Nix](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/367/hash-mismatch-error-on-plutus-and-nix)

If you look more closer at the entire error log, there is a mismatch in the sha256 singature of the derivation of ghc:
`hash mismatch in fixed-output derivation '/nix/store/7y3jr1jvzkj2146h7sivw0sfr2bhap3j-ghc-8.4.4-x86_64-deb8-linux.tar.xz`

Same answer, same workaround: the problem disappears when using the IOHK bianry cache for nix.
And there's is indeed an "IMPORTANT" mention at the begining of plutus REAME file asking to do this.

---

On NixOs:

```
# configuration.nix
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  # ... all the rest of the configuration of the server

  # iohk binary caches
  nix = 
  {
    binaryCaches          = [ "https://hydra.iohk.io" "https://iohk.cachix.org" ];
    binaryCachePublicKeys = [ "hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ=" "iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo=" ];
  };
}
```

---

Ubuntu and other Linuxes

Nix has a configuration in `/etc/nix/nix.conf`. So as to use the IOHK binary cache you have to modify this file:

In the documentation it is said

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/nix
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/nix/nix.conf
substituters = https://cache.nixos.org https://hydra.iohk.io
trusted-public-keys = iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
EOF
```